# Woocommerce New Order Custom Subject

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So if you go to woocommerce -> settings -> Emails -> Ne Order and at SUBJECT tab it says "Available placeholders: {site_title}, {order_date}, {order_number}" - What I need is to be able to put this -> **New order from {customer_name} ({customer_email}) : {item_names}** - Because I need to know from whom is the order, that's why I need the name, the email and the item that he/she purchased. Thank you in advance for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your functions or your plugin

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);

function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    $subject = sprintf( 'New Order (# %s) from %s %s %s', $order->id, $order->billing_first_name, $order->billing_last_name,  $order->billing_email);

    return $subject;
}
```

*To add order items use this `$order->get_items()`*

Comment: Awesome, it worked :) Thank you

Comment: @SasoriAkatsuki You're welcome :D